# Squaring colums with lapply

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I hope this question is simple enough to not warrant a reproducible example.

I have the following syntax:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(table_selection)[, (vars_of_interest) := lapply(.SD, sqrt, na.rm=TRUE), by = year, .SDcols=sds_of_interest]
```

I would like to square a sequence of columns instead of taking the square root, but I cannot find a similar function.

How should I do this?

Comment: So write one!  Wouldn't replacing `sqrt` with `function(x) x*x` give you what you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R data.table creating a custom function using lapply to create and reassign multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166518/r-data-table-creating-a-custom-function-using-lapply-to-create-and-reassign-mult)

Comment: @Limey, Yes it does, thank you very much. Very useful link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
setDT(table_selection)[, (vars_of_interest) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x^2), by = year, .SDcols=sds_of_interest]
```

Answer (score 1):

A very pure way:

```
setDT(table_selection)[, (vars_of_interest) := lapply(.SD, `^`, 2),
                       by = year,
                       .SDcols = sds_of_interest]
```